# Android app does not connect to internet properly and is stuck in attempting to login

Tags: android, phpmyadmin

I am working on an android app, I have used `localhost` it works fine but on online its not working. It works fine on connecting to `wampserver` but when I am trying to make it work online it doesn't connect and is always stuck in attempting to login don't know why this happens and my PHP code also works fine.

```
private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://omnibuscaps.esy.es/capstone/login.php";

private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

public final static int WHITE = 0xFFFFFFFF;
public final static int BLACK = 0xFF000000;
public final static int WIDTH = 400;
public final static int HEIGHT = 400;
public final static String STR = "";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //remove title
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    user = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
    pass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.accname2);
    bLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login);
    bLogin.setOnClickListener(this);



}//end onCreate Method

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     switch (v.getId()) {//start switch
     case R.id.login:
                new AttemptLogin().execute();

     // here we have used, switch case, because on login activity you may //also want to show registration button, so if the user is new ! we can go the //registration activity , other than this we could also do this without switch //case.
     default:
           break;
     }//end switch
}

class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Attempting for login...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          // here Check for success tag
        int success;
        String username = user.getText().toString();
        String password = pass.getText().toString();
        try {

            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

            Log.d("request!", "starting");

            JSONObject json = jsonparser.makeHttpRequest(
                   LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

             //checking  log for json response
            Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

            // success tag for json
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
              Log.d("Successfully Login!", json.toString());

              parseuser = user.getText().toString();//get username text
              parsepass = pass.getText().toString();//get password text
             Intent ii = new Intent(Login.this, Client.class);//initialize next activitty
             //Intent ii = new Intent(Login.this, NavActivity.class);
              ii.putExtra("usertext", parseuser);//store username
             ii.putExtra("passtext", parsepass);//store password
              finish();
             //this finish() //method is used to tell android os that we are done with current //activity now! Moving to other activity
             startActivity(ii);//start next activity

              return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            }else{
              pDialog.setMessage("Wrong username or password");
              pDialog.setCancelable(true);
              pDialog.show();
              return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

}

protected void onPostExecute(String message){
    pDialog.dismiss();
    if(message != null){
        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "OK na", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();      
    }
}
```

my log cat content

```
08-29 19:08:31.477: W/System.err(2353): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-29 19:08:31.477: W/System.err(2353):     at com.example.omniclient.Login$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(Login.java:111)
08-29 19:08:31.477: W/System.err(2353):     at com.example.omniclient.Login$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(Login.java:1)
08-29 19:08:31.477: W/System.err(2353):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
08-29 19:08:31.477: W/System.err(2353):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
08-29 19:08:31.477: W/System.err(2353):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
08-29 19:08:31.477: W/System.err(2353):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
08-29 19:08:31.477: W/System.err(2353):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
08-29 19:08:31.477: W/System.err(2353):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: Post any logcat content. Moreover, Check your network connection to make sure your app can access that site (can be tested by accessing by Web browser of the phone)

Comment: im using now a emulator to test it. my network connection is also fine, my logcat content

Comment: `JSONObject json = jsonparser.makeHttpRequest`, check if your `json` or `jsonparser` is null or not

Comment: Debug your app to find which line of code causes Exception

Comment: 'Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());'. json is null. Check before use. And if null return.

Answer (score 0):

Have you found out the cause of your problem yet? As I have commented, you should check whether `json` or `jsonparser` is null or not. Take a look at

```
JSONObject json = jsonparser.makeHttpRequest
```

Moreover, please post your `makeHttpRequest` will help us can find out the solution soon.

Hope this helps!